# Determine the pdf of the limiting distribution of random variables

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given $T_n$ is a continuous random variable with the pdf $\ \ f_{T_n}(t) = 8n(1-nt)\ I_{(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n})}(t)$ for $n\in N$. Find the pdf of the limiting distribution for the sequence $T_1, T_2, \ldots,$

**My thought:** First, we see that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_{T_n}(t) = 0$ for all $t\in R$. Now, we need to compute $P(T_n\leq t)$, but I could not see how to compute this from the given $\ f_{T_n}(t)$. I am not sure if this is correct, but I think $P(T_n\leq t) = \int_{\frac{1}{2n}}^{t} 8n(1-nx)dx = -3+ 8tn - 4n^2t^2$. Thus, $F_{T_n}(t) = -3+ 8tn - 4n^2t^2$ for $t\in (\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n})$, and $= 0$ otherwise. Now, when taking the limit of $F_{T_n}(t)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, we have: $-3 + \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 8tn - 4n^2t^2$ for $t\rightarrow 0$, but I don't know how to evaluate this limit.

Could someone please help me with this last step?

Comment: Given function cannot be a pdf because the area under this function does not equal to $1$.

Comment: You meant the pdf of $T_n$?? $\int_{\frac{1}{2n}}^{\frac{1}{n}} 8n(1-nt)dt = 8-4-4+1=1$ for $t\in (\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n})$.It's the valid pdf. Is my cdf above correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Your CDF is equal to smth for $t$ in interval $[1/2n,\, 1/n]$, $0$ for $t<1/2n$ and $1$ for $t>1/n$. Since $1/n \downarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty$, for any strictly positive $t$ there exists $n_0$ s.t. for all $n\geq n_0$ $F_{T_n}(t)=1$. Use definition for convergence in distribution and conclude.

Comment: Is "smth" = $-3+8tn-4n^2t^2$? I don't see why the CDF is $1$ for $t> \frac{1}{n}? Could you please help elaborate on this?

Comment: @NCh: I got the conclusion that $f_{T}(t) = I_{(0,\infty)}(t)$ where $T$ is a degenerate r.v such that $T_1,\ldots$ converges in distribution to $T$. Is this correct?

Comment: If $t>1/n$, $F_{T_n}(t)=P(T_n\leq t)=\int_{-\infty}^t f_{T_n}(x)dx=\int_{1/2n}^{1/n}8n(1-nx)dx=1$.

Comment: If you mean $F_T(t)=I_{(0,\infty)}(t)$, you are right. $T_n\xrightarrow{d} 0$ - r.v. degenerate at $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $f_{T_n}(t) = 8n(1-nt)\ I_{\left(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}\right)}(t)$ is positive only for $t\in\left(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ find that CDF of $T_n$ looks as follows: 
$$
F_{T_n}(t)=P(T_n\leq t)=\int_{-\infty}^t f_{T_n}(x)\,dx=\begin{cases}0, & t<\frac1{2n}\cr \ldots, & t\in\left(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}\right)\cr 1, & t \geq \frac{1}{n}\end{cases}
$$

$F_{T_n}(t)=0\to 0$ for all $t<0$. Since $\frac1n \downarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty$, for any strictly positive $t$ there exists $n_0$ such that  $F_{T_n}(t)=1$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

We see that for all $t\neq 0$
$$
F_{T_n}(t) \to F_T(t)=\begin{cases}0, & t<0\cr 1, & t\geq 0\end{cases}
$$
By definition, it means convergence in distribution to $T=0$ a.s. Limiting distribution is degenerate at $0$. We are not interested in the behaviour of CDF's at the point $t=0$ since this is the discontinuity point of limiting CDF.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your great help. Could you give this problem a try as well?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167372/pdf-of-limiting-distribution-of-t-n-x-n-n